# Need to get the ID of audiofile in android

Tags: android, listadapter

I can load a list with the following code

```
String[] projection = new String[] {
    Audio.Media._ID,
    Audio.Media.DATA,
    Audio.Media.DISPLAY_NAME};

        audioCursor = this.managedQuery(Audio.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI, 
            projection, null, null, Audio.Media.DISPLAY_NAME + " ASC");
        startManagingCursor(audioCursor);

        String[] columnsToMap = new String[] {Audio.Media.DISPLAY_NAME};
        int[] mapTo = new int[] {R.id.text1};

        ListAdapter mAdapter = new SimpleCursorAdapter(this, 
            R.layout.song_item , audioCursor, columnsToMap, mapTo);
        this.setListAdapter(mAdapter);
```

and in the onListItemClick I can get the file name like this

```
protected void onListItemClick(ListView l, View v, int position, long id) {
    String DisplayName;

    DisplayName =(String) ((TextView) v).getText(); // get name to compare
    Toast.makeText(this,DisplayName, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
```

but what I need is the original Audio.Media._ID number from the top.  How can retrieve this number from the onListItemClick?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are doing bad design.

You **should not** get the value from the view. You will have to jump your cursor to the `position` and use the values from the cursor. The `id` param will hold the `_ID` of the record.

```
if (audioCursor.moveToPosition(position)) {
    String DisplayName;
    DisplayName=audioCursor.getString(audioCursor.getColumnIndex(Audio.Media.DISPLAY_NAME));

}
```

Comment: Oh Yeah? Well my design was much worse then you thought.  My plan was to the take that ID number and then re search through Audio.Media to get Audio.Media.DATA!  Your answer showed me how to directly get the DATA form the param.  Thank you